# When is a commutative monoid with its natural order "continuous"?

Tags: abstract-algebra, lattice-orders, monoid

Let $A$ be a commutative monoid and define its natural *pre*order by:

$$x\leq y :\Leftrightarrow \exists k\in A: x + k = y$$

Assume $\leq$ is antisymmetric.

> What kind of "obvious" properties can one assume such that:
>   $$ \bigvee_{i\in I} (x_i + y) = \bigvee_{i\in I} x_i + y$$ whenever these suprema exist?

Note that in any case we have: $$\bigvee_{i\in I} (x_i + y_i)  \leq \bigvee_{i\in I} x_i + \bigvee_{i\in I} y_i$$

so the question comes down to when the other inequality holds.

---

Movitaion: The above property is necessary to show that [“continuous monoids” are “complete”](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1920903/a-continuous-monoid-is-complete).

Comment: I guess you are excluding $I=\emptyset$? Because, otherwise $0=\bigvee_{i \in I} (x_i+y) = (\bigvee_{i \in I} x_i) + y = 0+y=y$.

Comment: @Nex Actually, that's a good point... I suppose I do

Comment: One sufficient condition is for $y ^ {-1}$ to exist (see Glass "Partially Ordered Groups" Lemma 2.3.6)

Comment: @xodarap Sorry, but I also disagree with this comment. Since $\leq$ is supposed to be antisymmetric, there is no inverse (except for the identity of the monoid). Indeed, if $x$ has an inverse $-x$ (in additive notation), then $0 \leq x$ since $0+x = x$ and $x \leq 0$ since $x + (-x) = 0$. By antisymmetry, $x = 0$.

Comment: @Nex You're perfectly right. I delete my comment.